# Unable to sort sequlize results based on joined table fields

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am working with 3 sequelize models as described below:

```
tags:
id
tag_name

product_tags:
id
tag_id --> Foreign Key 'id' from tags
product_id --> Foreign Key 'id' from products
tag_score

products:
id
name
```

I wanted to get the product names along with their associated tags and the tag score and sort them by the score, as described in the SQL query below.

```
select t.tag_name, p.name, pt.tag_score from tags t inner join product_tags pt on t.id = pt.tag_id inner join products p on pt.product_id = p.id order by pt.tag_score desc;
```

As per the sequelize documentation,this can be accomplished by an order clause like so:

```
order: [this.db.ProductTag, 'tag_score', 'DESC']
```

However, I get the error message: Unable to find a valid association for model, 'ProductTag'

Can someone please point out what I'm missing here?

EDIT: 
Sequelize query is below:

```
return this.db.Product.findAll({
  attributes: ['name'],
  include: [
    {
      model: this.db.Tag,
      as: 'tags',
      through: this.db.ProductTag,
      foreignKey: 'tag_id',
      otherKey: 'product_id',
      where: {
        tag_name: {
          $regexp: regexString
        }
      },
      required: true,
      include: [
        {
          model: this.db.ProductTag,
          as: 'product_tags',
          attributes: ['tag_score']
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  order: [this.db.ProductTag, 'tag_score', 'DESC']
});
```

Comment: Will you please post whole sequlize query ?

Comment: try `order: [ ['tag_score', 'DESC'] ]`

Comment: @VivekDoshi I've added the Sequelize query as you requested

Comment: @Ellebkey I tried what you suggested, got the following message:

Unknown column 'Product.tag_score' in 'order clause'

Comment: Oh I didnt saw your models, yes you get that error cause `tag_score` is on `product_tags` model not `Products`. I'm not quite sure how to order this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that sequelize create subquery, so you need to change your order to get `false` in this if:

```
if (
          subQuery
          && Array.isArray(order)
          && order[0]
          && !(order[0] instanceof Association)
          && !(typeof order[0] === 'function' && order[0].prototype instanceof Model)
          && !(typeof order[0].model === 'function' && order[0].model.prototype instanceof Model)
          && !(typeof order[0] === 'string' && model && model.associations !== undefined && model.associations[order[0]])
        ) {
          subQueryOrder.push(this.quote(order, model, '->'));
        }
        mainQueryOrder.push(this.quote(order, model, '->'));
```

Or you can try to use `sequelize.literal()`. Like: 
`order: [[sequelize.literal('tag_score DESC')]]`